# Error saving UTF8mb4 Emoji in mysql (mariadb) database via PHPmyAdmin Error #1366

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, utf8mb4

I'm getting a strange error. I am only able to save ❤️ in the mysql db. All other emojis i tested are not storaged in the database.

```
Warning: #1366 Wrong string
```

See screenshot.

I did the following things

```
1. In my.cnf set default-character-set = utf8mb4
2. Create new database with collation utf8mb4_general_ci
3. Create new table table with collation utf8mb4_general_ci
4. Set collation from row to utf8mb4_general_ci
```

I restarted mysql server. But no chance. I have absolutly no idea why i can storage ❤️ but no other emojis.

Setup:
Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
PLESK 18.0.32

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its a problem with the PHPmyAdmin Version.
The emojis storaged correctly in the database. If i make a select via PHP, the emojis are displayed correctly.

Comment: Can you include the phpmyadmin version in your answer? So that those who encounter the same problem can make assumptions if this is the same problem for them.

Comment: phpMyAdmin has had proper Unicode support for a very, very long time (probably since version 3, or roughly 2008), so the problem may be more nuanced. On the main page of phpMyAdmin, what is the value in the "Server connection collation" dropdown? Which phpMyAdmin version are you using, and are you using MySQL or MariaDB? I'm using phpMyAdmin 5.1.0-rc1, MariaDB 10.3, PHP 7.4, and my Server connection collation is utf8mb4_general_ci; the rest of my configuration matches what you've described and I have no problems. I'd like to help you get to the bottom of this.